# How to make radio button unchecked if click on another option in quiz application using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an online quiz application in which multiple choice questions are there. So I want to make if user has selected an option mistakenly, and now he/she want to change his/her option and selected another option. So how should I do that?

Below is my HTML for radio buttons:

```
<input class="form-check-input ans-radio" type="radio" name="option"  id="exampleRadios1" value="1" onclick="selectedOpt();">
<label class="form-check-label ans-label" for="exampleRadios1" id="label1">Option A</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option"  id="exampleRadios2" value="2" onclick="selectedOpt();">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2" id="label2">Option B</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option"  id="exampleRadios3" value="3" onclick="selectedOpt();">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3" id="label3">Option C</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="exampleRadios4" value="4" onclick="selectedOpt();">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4" id="label4">Option D</label>
```

Below is my JavaScript function to handle user clicked option:

```
  function selectedOpt(){
      var selectedOption = [], selectedQuestion = [];
      var useroptions = "", questionid = "";
      $('[name="option"]').each(function(i,e){
         if($(e).is(':checked')){
            selectedOption.push(e.value);
         }
      });
      document.querySelectorAll('input[name="question"]').forEach(function(elem){
          selectedQuestion.push(elem.value);
      });
     useroptions = selectedOption.join();
     questionid = selectedQuestion.join();
     console.log("user options || "+useroptions);
     console.log("question id || "+questionid);
   }
```

Above function is storing user options in an array. So if a user has selected Option A and again selected Option A then in an array two similiar options get added and if user has changed option then that option also get added in Array. So by this, his/her total score and result may get affected.
I want that if user has changed his option then previous option should be removed and new option should get added in array.

Comment: your question is unclear. The js functon you use to handle the click event always scans the whole document and evaluates the form options from scratch to build those arrays. Plus you used both jquery and web api to do the same thing and still is not clear what's supposed to be the element `input[name=question]` because you didn't include it in your html. And the `if $(e).is(':checked')` condition is not needed since you can put it inside the selector like `[name="option"]:checked`

Comment: I simply want to ask that how to clear previous value to fresh value in a an array? Suppose you have mistakenly clicked on option A but now you want to pick option B. So that option A should be removed from array and option B should be added in an array.

Comment: There might be a HTML solution: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/html/how+to+select+only+one+radio+button+in+html

Comment: Okay, and then how should I pass all user marked answers to backend (using spring boot) when clicking on submit button?

Comment: you are not removing anything from the array. you are always creating a new empty one filling it with ALL the `[name="option"]:checked` in the document everytime a single radio option was clicked. To make that function more meaningful you should just run it once when the form submit event occurs or when any other "submitting" event is fired like the click of a "send results" button.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very crude state management system: it's flexible enough to define your own functions when updating the `selectedOption` array: you can push any number of items in there, make them unique or have a function that actually removes the last selected and adds the new one. It can also handle any number of options.

```js
const rBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input")

const initState = () => {
  let _selectedOption = []
  return {
    get selectedOption() {
      return _selectedOption
    },
    set selectedOption(val) {
      _selectedOption = val
    },
  }
}

const initActions = (state) => ({
  addToSelected(payload) {
    state.selectedOption = [...state.selectedOption, payload]
  },
  ensureLatest(fn) {
    return (payload) => {
      // ensures that the last item in the selectedOption is always
      // the latest option selected
      state.selectedOption = state.selectedOption.filter(e => e !== payload)
      fn(payload)
    }
  },
  addToSelectedUniq(payload) {
    this.ensureLatest(this.addToSelected)(payload)
    state.selectedOption = [...new Set(state.selectedOption)]
  },
  removeLastSelectedOption() {
    state.selectedOption.pop()
  }
})

const state = initState()
const actions = initActions(state)

// this function ensures that the previous choice is removed if
// a new one is picked; also ensures that the same value cannot
// be in the array twice (actually not needed, if the last is
// always removed)
const onSelect = (e) => {
  actions.removeLastSelectedOption()
  actions.addToSelectedUniq(e.target.value)
  console.log(state)
}

rBtns.forEach(rBtn => {
  rBtn.addEventListener('change', onSelect)
})
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input ans-radio" type="radio" name="option" id="exampleRadios1" value="1">
<label class="form-check-label ans-label" for="exampleRadios1" id="label1">Option A</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="exampleRadios2" value="2">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2" id="label2">Option B</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="exampleRadios3" value="3">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3" id="label3">Option C</label>
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="option" id="exampleRadios4" value="4">
<label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4" id="label4">Option D</label>
```